# Ckeditor 5 with Angular 7 font color in toolbar does not appear

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am trying to display font color in CKeditor 5 toolbar in my angular 7 application what am I doing wrong? I have [stackblitzed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckeditor-ytpjts) my issue, and here is the code :

Here is my typescript file with config :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  editor = ClassicEditor;
  data: any = `<p>Hello, world!</p>`;
  config: any = {
    placeholder: 'Enter new message...',
    toolbar: [
      'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'fontColor', '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'insertTable', '|', 'undo', 'redo'
    ]
  };
}
```

And here is my html file :

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [data]="data" [config]="config"></ckeditor>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic which is a classic and doesn't have the color option on top.

See demo https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html

If the color option is on high priority, you can use another ckeditor module. See ckeditor 4 guide here:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/colorbutton.html